# SemanticException when call executeUpdate() of JPA for update a Clob column in hibernate 6.3

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to update a Clob column in a table and when call executeUpdate() method of JPA api, throws a semantic Exception.

this is part of my hibernate class for this column:

```
   @Column(name="DES_PDFSETTING_URPST")
    public Clob getDesPdfsettingUrpst() {
        return this.desPdfsettingUrpst;
    }
    
    public void setDesPdfsettingUrpst(Clob desPdfsettingUrpst) {
        this.desPdfsettingUrpst = desPdfsettingUrpst;
    }
```

update query:

```
 CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaUpdate<UserReportSettings> update = cb.
                    createCriteriaUpdate(UserReportSettings.class);
            Root e = update.from(UserReportSettings.class);
            update.set("desPdfsettingUrpst", ClobProxy.generateProxy(pdfSettings));
            update.where(cb.equal(e.get("seqUrpstUrpst"), seq));
            session.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
```

description of exception:

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot assign expression of type 'java.io.Serializable' to target path 'alias_2044729830.desPdfsettingUrpst' of type 'java.sql.Clob'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertAssignable(TypecheckUtil.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.update.SqmUpdateStatement.set(SqmUpdateStatement.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.update.SqmUpdateStatement.set(SqmUpdateStatement.java:37)
    at com.src.connectors.UserReportSettingsConnector.updatePDFSettings(UserReportSettingsConnector.java:198)
    at com.ssd.core.ui.report.Report.printReport(Report.java:1180)
    at com.src.controllers.RSRC7001.getJasperLegalInfos(RSRC7001.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.ssd.core.controller.CoreWebServlet.onRequest(CoreWebServlet.java:53)
    at com.ssd.core.controller.CoreServlet.handleRequest(CoreServlet.java:139)
    at com.ssd.core.controller.CoreServlet.doPost(CoreServlet.java:107)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ssd.core.security.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

my database is oracle and i am using hibernate 6.3.

I was using hibernate 5.2.18 and jpa 2.1 before and I didn't have any problems. but in hibernate 6.3 and jpa 3.1 this exception happened.
I Know that in set() method, assertAssignable() will be called and this method check the SqmPathSource of expressions, but i do not know what i must pass for value to not throw exception.